# I can't send documents in pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

so I'm trying to send a `.txt` file using `pyTelegramBotAPI` but it won't work

Error :

```
Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: file must be non-empty
```

code :

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=["CAPTURED"])
def sendcaps(message):
    
    if "captured.txt" in os.listdir():
        caps=open("captured.txt","r")
        if caps.read() != "":
            bot.send_document(chat_id=message.chat.id,document=caps)
        else:
            bot.reply_to(message,"None")
```

As you see it's impossible for the file to be empty, cuz it won't slip through the `if condition` in the first place and I also tried to open the file in `rb` mode

Answer (score 0):

When you did `caps.read()` you read the file and file object's position went to the end of the file. Then you tried sending same file object `caps` as a document. I am not 100% sure, but suppose that under the hood `bot.send_document()` calls `read()` method of the file object, and it fails with `caps` file object, because its position is already at the end. To return position to the start you sould call `seek(0)` method.

And as per [examples](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/373ee4b45ba34cbe74e9dbb8bfdca723c80a39d4/examples/asynchronous_telebot/send_file_example.py) `send_document()` expects file object opened in the binary mode.

This code should work:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["CAPTURED"])
def sendcaps(message):
    if "captured.txt" in os.listdir():
        with open("captured.txt", "rb") as caps:
            if len(caps.read()) > 0:
                # Return file object's position to the start.
                caps.seek(0)
                bot.send_document(chat_id=message.chat.id,document=caps)
            else:
                bot.reply_to(message,"None")
```